# Can I use “on” like this?

Tags: prepositions

There are G block on B block, B block on C block and C block on the desk.

“G block is on the desk”

“G block is on the C block”

“G block is on the B block”

Are all of these three statements above technically correct?

For example, we call the book on the mass of books on the desk “the book on the desk.”

https://www.123rf.com/photo_71338859_desk-full-of-open-books-over-green-blackboard.html

Comment: Sorry if it is all about logics… but I tried to relate my question to English.

Comment: Please give the blocks different labels. It is difficult to know if "A" at the beginning of a sentence is being used as an article or the name of a block.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial description makes it sound like the blocks appear in the following manner:

[image: Image of three blocks stacked on top of each other with a desk on the bottom. The blocks are labeled G, B, C from top to bottom.]

If this is the correct orientation, I would say that only your last sentence is purely correct (though it needs an article).

When we use "on" to relate to physical position, we generally mean something that's directly above/touching something else. While it's correct in your third sentence, it is not the case in the other two.

If I looked at the image above and read the sentence, "The G block is on the desk", I would say that that statement is incorrect. The G block is on the B block. Only the C block is on the desk.

This isn't always the case - in your example with the blocks it feels like you're trying to precisely explain where the blocks are because you describe the setup of the blocks so specifically.

In the case of the books it's a bit different because a pile of books on a desk where you don't actually know which book is which, then it makes sense to say "on" even if the book may not technically be touching the desk.

That said, I'd be more likely to say something like:

> The book is somewhere in that stack/pile on the desk.

In this way, it's the stack that's on the desk, not the specific book.

Comment: But we say “hand on the hand” even though hands are in gloves.

Comment: I've never heard someone say "hand on the hand" even when there weren't gloves involved, to be honest? But we say "on the bed" even though there's sheets - there's a difference in some cases, but if you pointed at blocks clearly labeled as they are in the picture and told me "Block G is on the desk", I would tell you that you were wrong.

Comment: ♦ Could you tell me more information about “on the bed” case?

Comment: I'd argue that the "bed" in that case includes the sheets, much as your body includes any clothes. "Put your head on my shoulder" doesn't imply there being a shirt or not, so at times you have to be specific - "She put her hand on her bare shoulder" or (for the bed) "He sat on the unmade bed." If your table had a tablecloth, we'd accept saying that something was "on the table" because the cloth becomes part of the table. Does that make sense?

Comment: ♦ I perfectly understood, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is more common in many contexts to use "block A" instead of "A block", and so on. So block G is on block B, block B is on block C, and block C is on the desk. Using the article is not necessary.

Whether you would say block G is on the desk would depend on context. You might ask somebody to bring "the block labelled G which is on my desk", and you hearer would understand it may not be directly on the desk. On the other hand if I was arranging the blocks and was told to "put block G on the desk" I would put it directly on the desk.